# Pipe for returning Base64 version of image URL Angular 6

Tags: angular, base64, angular6

I have an angular 6 application and in some part of html codes, I`m showing images in Base64 format. For doing that I created a pipe for returning Base64 version of data that I send to the pipe.
This is my pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'base64Imag',
})

export class Base64ImagPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let Base64 = BASE_LIBRARY_CODES;

    if (typeof(value) != 'undefined') {
       return Base64.encode(value);
    }else{
       return '';
    }   
  }
}
```

But it returns this:

```
<img src="unsafe:data:image/svg+xml;.....">
```

How can I fix "**unsafe**" in pipe?

Answer (score 2):

This is the the way I found and works with help of friends here:

Pipe:

```
transform(value: any, args?: any) {
    if (typeof(value) != 'undefined') {
       return 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(value);
    }else{
       return '';
    }   
}
```

In component:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
constructor(public _DomSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
```

In html code:

```
<img width="50" [src]="_DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(SVG_URL | base64Imag)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your transform should use the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusturl)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeUrl, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'base64Imag',
})

export class Base64ImagPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(value: any, args?: any): SafeUrl {
    let Base64 = BASE_LIBRARY_CODES;

    if (typeof(value) != 'undefined') {
       return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(Base64.encode(value));
    }else{
       return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('');
    }   
  }
}
```

> [WARNING: calling this method with untrusted user data exposes your application to XSS security risks!](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusturl)

Comment: thanks a lot. I`m using this now return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(btoa(value)); but still get "unsafe" in result?!!  could you please help me?